# The modified time (auto_now) works on Django but not in Heroku when deployed

Tags: python, django, heroku

So this is my code in class *Post(models.Model)*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and snippet of my code in *home.html*

```
{% if post.date_modified is not Null %}
<small class="text-secondary font-italic">⁠— modified at {{ post.date_modified }}</small>
{% endif %}
```

The codes work perfectly in Django, however, when I deployed them in Heroku: the `date_modified` of posts are filled (same date and time as `date_posted`) so`date_modified` is not `Null`. This makes them show up even if the post is not updated by the user.

I have already done:

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`
3. `git add -A, git commit -m "message", git push heroku master`
4. `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations`
5. `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

Does anyone know how to fix this or explain why this happened? I can't seem to find any solution related to this. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: `if post.date_modified is not Null` makes no sense. `Null` does not exists in the template, unless you passed `None`, for example through a context processor.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem can I pass a ```None``` value in ```auto_now```? I tried doing ```if date_modified != date_posted``` but it seems like the value of ```date_modified``` is higher than ```date_posted``` (not editing anything). I am kind of newbie in this. Is there a documentation of where can I look through this?